# Python asyncio task got bad yield

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am confused about how to play around with the `asyncio` module in Python 3.4. I have a `searching` API for a search engine, and want to each search request to be run either parallel, or asynchronously, so that I don't have to wait for one search finish to start another.

Here is my high-level searching API to build some objects with the raw search results. The search engine itself is using some kind of asyncio mechanism, so I won't bother with that.

```
# No asyncio module used here now
class search(object):
  ...
  self.s = some_search_engine()
  ...
  def searching(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ret = {}
    # do some raw searching according to args and kwargs and build the wrapped results
    ...
    return ret
```

To try to async the requests, I wrote following test case to test how I can interact my stuff with the `asyncio` module.

```
# Here is my testing script
@asyncio.coroutine
def handle(f, *args, **kwargs):
  r = yield from f(*args, **kwargs)
  return r

s = search()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(handle(s.searching, arg1, arg2, ...))
loop.close()
```

By running with pytest, it will return a `RuntimeError: Task got bad yield : {results from searching...}`, when it hits the line `r = yield from ...`.

I also tried another way.

```
# same handle as above
def handle(..):
  ....
s = search()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
        asyncio.async(handle(s.searching, arg11, arg12, ...)),
        asyncio.async(handle(s.searching, arg21, arg22, ...)),
        ...
        ]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

By running this test case by pytest, it passes but some weird exception from the search engine will raise. And it says `Future/Task exception was never retrieved`.

Things I wish to ask:

1. For my 1st try, is that the right way to use `yield from`, by returning the actual result from a function call?
2. I think I need to add some sleep to my 2nd test case to wait for the task finish, but how should I do that? And how can I get my function calls to return in my 2nd test case?
3. Is that a good way to implement asyncio with an existing module, by creating an async handler to handle requests?
4. If the answer to question 2 is NO, does every client calls to the class `search` needs to include `loop = get_event_loop()` this kind of stuffs to async the requests?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that you can't just call existing synchronous code as if it was an `asyncio.coroutine` and get asynchronous behavior. When you call `yield from searching(...)`, you're only going to get asynchronous behavior if `searching` itself is actually an `asyncio.coroutine`, or at least returns an `asyncio.Future`. Right now, `searching` is just a regular synchronous function, so calling `yield from searching(...)` is just going to throw an error, because it doesn't return a `Future` or coroutine.

To get the behavior you want, you'll need to have an asynchronous version of `searching` in addition to a `synchronous` version (or just drop the synchronous version altogether if you don't need it). You have a few options to support both:

1. Rewrite `searching` as an `asyncio.coroutine` that it uses `asyncio`-compatible calls to do its I/O, rather than blocking I/O.  This will make it work in an `asyncio` context, but it means you won't be able to call it directly in a synchronous context anymore. Instead, you'd need to also provide an alternative synchronous `searching` method that starts an `asyncio` event loop and calls `return loop.run_until_complete(self.searching(...))`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155138/how-can-i-write-asyncio-coroutines-that-optionally-act-as-regular-functions) for more details on that.
2. Keep your synchronous implementation of `searching`, and provide an alternative asynchronous API that uses [`BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) to run your the `searching` method in a background thread:

   ```
   class search(object):
     ...
     self.s = some_search_engine()
     ...
     def searching(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ret = {}
       ...
       return ret

      @asyncio.coroutine
      def searching_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
         loop = kwargs.get('loop', asyncio.get_event_loop())
         try:
             del kwargs['loop']  # assuming searching doesn't take loop as an arg
         except KeyError:
             pass
         r = yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, self.searching, *args)  # Passing None tells asyncio to use the default ThreadPoolExecutor
         return r
   ```

   Testing script:

   ```
   s = search()
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(s.searching_async(arg1, arg2, ...))
   loop.close()
   ```

   This way, you can keep your synchronous code as is, and at least provide methods that can be used in `asyncio` code without blocking the event loop. It's not as clean a solution as it would be if you actually used asynchronous I/O in your code, but its better than nothing.
3. Provide two completely separate versions of `searching`, one that uses blocking I/O, and one that's `asyncio`-compatible. This gives ideal implementations for both contexts, but requires twice the work.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I've seen some C++ coding about asyncio and they used `void foo(..) { bind(foo_callin, _1, _2, ...); }` and in `void foo_callin(..)` doing the real implementation. Is this the idea quite similar to your 2nd option?

Comment: @ourlord Yes, if the `foo` function you're talking about is calling `foo_callin` in a background thread (and it sounds like that might be what's happening, depending on what is called addition to `bind(foo_callin, ..)`), it's doing something very similar to the second option.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that the `bind` function is under a self-implement `async` namespace which should include a thread/task scheduler or manager. Things are getting really clear now! Thank you again for your comments!