# Make my own function as asyncio function in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I would like to use asyncio module in Python to achieve doing request tasks in parallel because my current request tasks works in sequence, which means it is blocking.

I have read the documents of asyncio module in Python, and I have wrote some simple code as follows, however it doesn't work as I thought.

```
import asyncio
class Demo(object):

    def demo(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        tasks = [task1.verison(), task2.verison()]
        result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
        loop.close()
        print(result)

class Task():
   @asyncio.coroutine
   def version(self):
       print('before')
       result = yield from differenttask.GetVersion() 
       # result = yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
       print('after')
```

I found out that all the example they give use asyncio function to make the non-blocking works, how to make own function works as a asyncio?

What I want to achieve is that for a task it will execute the request and doesn't wait the response then it switch to next task. When I tried this: I get `RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: 'hostname'`, which *hostname* is one item in my expected result.

so as @AndrewSvetlov said, differentask.GetVersion() is a regular synchronous function. I have tried the second method suggested in [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172821/python-asyncio-task-got-bad-yield?rq=1), --- the one `Keep your synchronous implementation of searching...blabla`

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def version(self):
    return (yield from asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, self._proxy.GetVersion()))
```

And it still doesn't work, Now the error is 
`Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<Task.version() done, defined at /root/syi.py:34> exception=TypeError("'dict' object is not callable",)>`

I'm not sure if I understand if it right, please advice.

Comment: What isn't working? What specific problems are you having?

Comment: What I want to achieve is that for a task it will execute the request and doesn't wait the response then it switch to next task. I have error :     `RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: 'hostname' ` hostname is one item in my result.

Comment: `differenttask.GetVersion()` should be coroutine to be used with `await` syntax. Looks like you have a regular function.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Yes, GetVersion() is a regular synchronous function. I have tried the second way suggested in [task got bad yield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172821/python-asyncio-task-got-bad-yield?rq=1), which makes a regular function as async function if I understand it right. But it still doesn't work...I will add my changes in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def version(self):
    return (yield from asyncio.get_event_loop()
            .run_in_executor(None, self._proxy.GetVersion))
```

Please pay attention `self._proxy.GetVersion` is not called here but a reference to function is passed into the loop executor.

Now all IO performed by `GetVersion()` is still synchronous but executed in a thread pool.

It may have benefits for you or may not. 
If the whole program uses thread pool based solution only you need `concurrent.futures.ThreadPool` perhaps, not `asyncio`.
If the most part of the application is built on top of asynchronous libraries but only relative small part uses thread pools -- that's fine.

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor()`, do you know why? And I have checked `concurrent.futures.ThreadPool` and as you suggested, I think it suits to my scenarios better than `asyncio`.

Comment: `self._proxy.GetVersion` should be a regular function for `run_in_executor()` usage.
Your `version()` wrapper should be a coroutine to be used with `yield from` statement.