# Precise specification of __await__

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

The Python Language Reference specifies [`object.__await__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__await__#object.__await__) as follows:

> `object.__await__(self)`
>
> Must return an iterator. Should be used to implement awaitable objects. For instance, `asyncio.Future` implements this method to be compatible with the await expression.

That's it. I find this specification very vague and not very specific (ironically). Ok, it should return an iterator, but can it be an arbitrary iterator? Obviously not:

```py
import asyncio


class Spam:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from range(10)


async def main():
    await Spam()


asyncio.run(main())
```

```
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: 0
```

I'm assuming the `asyncio` event loop expects a specific kind of object being yielded by the iterator. Then what *exactly* should it yield? (And why isn't this documented?)

---

**Edit:** as far as I can see, this isn't documented anywhere. But I've been investigating on my own, and I think that the key to understanding what objects the `asyncio` expects its coroutines to yield lies in [`task_step_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/529f42645d38b6b0075f256814dfb3d220ac7d92/Modules/_asynciomodule.c#L2624-L2973) in `_asynciomodule.c`.

---

**Update:** I've made a PR to the cpython repository with the aim of clarifying this: ["Clarify the vague specification of `object.__await__`"](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/22320).

The PR has now been merged and should be available in the docs for Python 3.10+.

Comment: Note that you don't need to read C code to understand the asyncio event loop. The C code is just an accelerated version of the canonical [Python code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c8c70e78762315643fcd132911bad38842a3e8af/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L278), which is kept and actively maintained for the sake of non-C-backed implementations such as PyPy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The *language* doesn't care which iterator you return. The error comes from a *library*, asyncio, which has specific ideas about the kind of values that must be produced by the iterator. Asyncio requires `__await__` to produce asyncio futures (including their subtypes such as tasks) or `None`. Other libraries, like curio and trio, will expect different kinds of values. Async libraries by and large don't document their expectations from `__await__` because they consider it an implementation detail.

As far as asyncio is concerned, you're supposed to be using higher-level constructs, such as futures and tasks, and await those, in addition to coroutines. There is rarely a need to implement `__await__` manually, and even [then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56079900/1600898) you should use it to delegate the signals of another awaitable. Writing an `__await__` that creates and yields a fresh suspend-value of its own requires it to be coupled with the event loop and have knowledge of its internals.

You can think of `__await__` as a tool to write a library similar to asyncio. If you are the author of such a library, the current specification is sufficient because you can yield whatever you like from the iterator, only the code in your event loop will observe the yielded values. If you're not in that position, you probably have no need to implement `__await__`.

Comment: That clears it up. Although whoever wrote that specification could have at least cared to add something along the lines of "the values expected from this iterator are specific to the event loop implementation", and in particular a note about `asyncio` (i.e. "only yield from `asyncio` tasks, futures, and coroutines").

Comment: @Anakhand I agree with the sentiment, although specifying it is harder than it seems, since `await` is a very general mechanism which could be used for control flow [not tied to](https://morestina.net/blog/1253/continuations) a classic event loop. But even so, awaited objects always need _,some_ sort of driver. I understand that they wouldn't mention asyncio specifically, as it might have still been in the provisional status at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks can only wait on other tasks / futures. From the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_asynciomodule.c#L2795):

```c
    /* Check if `result` is FutureObj or TaskObj (and not a subclass) */
    /* ... */

    /* Check if `result` is None */
    /* ... error */

    /* Check if `result` is a Future-compatible object */
    /* ... */

    /* Check if `result` is a generator */
    /* ... */

    /* The `result` is none of the above */
    o = task_set_error_soon(
        task, PyExc_RuntimeError, "Task got bad yield: %R", result);
    Py_DECREF(result);
    return o;
```

---

Edit: If I understand correctly this restriction is only imposed on tasks, and normal futures can wait on any iterable returned from `__await__`, though the point is probably that the iterable returned yields to the event loop, then ultimately ends up returning a result.

Comment: Yep, I basically found the same by delving into CPython code in `_asynciomodule.c` (particularly `task_step_impl`, which is the function you're quoting). Now the question is what exactly does the implementation do with these futures/tasks, and what the value of these objects should be.

Comment: *Tasks can only wait on other tasks / futures.* - note that this only applies to asyncio. [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are perfectly able to await on objects that are neither tasks nor futures - in fact, they (intentionally) don't expose those abstractions in the first place.