# How does asyncio.gather work under the hood?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to know how `asyncion.gather()` works under the hood. I observed its source code and found out it just calls the `_ensure_future` function for each of the arguments passed to it. The `ensure_future` returns the argument passed to it if it is already a future or tries to return `loop.create_task(arg)` if the arg is coroutine and awaitable. So basically it doesn't do much when the arg is created using `asyncio.create_task()`. Anyways `gather()` returns an object of the class `_GatheringFuture` to whom `children` list is passed. `children` consists of all the futures returned by calling `_ensure_future()` method for each arg passed to the `gather()`.
This class, `_GatheringFuture`, does not do anything. It just has a cancel method to make it possible to cancel the tasks (or futures).

But I think the important part is that it inherits from `futures.Future`. So I looked into `futures.Future.__await__` method, here's the source code:

```
def __await__(self):
    if not self.done():
        self._asyncio_future_blocking = True
        yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
    if not self.done():
        raise RuntimeError("await wasn't used with future")
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
```

It just yields itself. How does that make it possible for all the tasks or futures passed to the `gather()` to run concurrently? I don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the inner workings of asyncio, but we can explain some of what is going on here.

Firstly async is just syntax sugar for [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).

Secondly coroutines are basically [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) with some extra stuff.

Everything we see in the `__await__` implementation can be explained via generators:

```py
def __await__(self):
    if not self.done():
        self._asyncio_future_blocking = True
        yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
    if not self.done():
        raise RuntimeError("await wasn't used with future")
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
```

What this means is that as long as the task is not yet 'done' it will continue to `yield`.  And when it's done it will `return`.

Let's define a simple generator and see how that behaves:

```py
def create_task():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i
    return "done"

task = create_task()

while True:
    val = next(task)
    print(val)
```

When we run this we see:

```
0
1
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 2
      1 while True:
----> 2     val = next(task)
      3     print(val)

StopIteration: done
```

So `return` from a generator raises a `StopIteration` exception containing the return value.

That means we can make something a bit like an event loop for executing generator tasks, like this:

```py
def run(task):
    while True:
        try:
            next(task)
        except StopIteration as e:
            return e.value
```

If we run that:

```
In [21]: run(create_task())
Out[21]: 'done'
```

You asked:

> How does that make it possible for all the tasks or futures passed to the `gather()` to run concurrently?

What we can see above is that our asyncio event loop is doing something like calling `next` on a coroutine. And each time that coroutine `yield`s the control flow will pass back to the event loop.

So in the case of `gather` it has a list of task coroutines to manage.

Let's extend our toy example a bit further to see how that might work:

```py
def create_task1(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
    return 'task 1'


def create_task2():
    for x in 'abc':
        yield x
    return 'task 2'


def run(*tasks):
    results = []
    active_tasks = list(tasks)
    while len(results) < len(tasks):
        for task in active_tasks:
            try:
                print(next(task))
            except StopIteration as e:
                results.append(e.value)
                del active_tasks[active_tasks.index(task)]
    return results
```

When we run this we see:

```py
In [33]: run(create_task1(6), create_task2())
0
a
1
b
2
c
3
4
5
Out[33]: ['task 2', 'task 1']
```

The `print` output shows how the execution of the two tasks is interleaved - each time one of them yields, the other is able to proceed a step, orchestrated by the loop in the runner.

Meanwhile the runner is collecting the results from the completed generators and eventually returns them.

It's important to note that async Python is still single-threaded, and subject to the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

So when we talk about "concurrency" we mean something different from "parallelism" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050257/202168).

In Python the single-threaded concurrency of `async` is useful when the tasks are doing work that is able to release the GIL. This essentially means I/O, for example waiting for data on a network port (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270846/202168).

Comment: Thank you. your examples were great. but the thing is you're using a while loop to iterate as long as there is a task. But there is no loop in `Future.__await__`. it just yields itself one time. and why does it yield itself? why doesn't it call send method on the coroutines?

Comment: `__await__` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__await__#object.__await__ "must return an iterator", I guess `yield self` is a way to satisfy that requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966273/202168 says that in asyncio lib specifically the `__await__` should produce an asyncio Future (i.e. `self`). There's no loop needed there because it is just a future, the loop is implemented at a level above. There is [a loop in `gather`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L777) but obviously there's more going on than my toy example

Comment: TBH I haven't gone deep enough into the asyncio implementation to understand and explain everything.