# async - sync - async calls in one python event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Let's say I have a class which uses asyncio loop internally and doesn't have async interface:

```
class Fetcher:
    _loop = None
    def get_result(...):
        """
        After 3 nested sync calls async tasks are finally called with *run_until_complete*
        """
        ...
```

I use all advantages of asyncio internally and don't have to care about it in the outer code.

But then I want to call 3 `Fetcher` instances in one event loop. If I had `async def` interface there would be no problem: `asyncio.gather` could help me. Is there really no other way to do it without supporting [both interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163654/1401639)? Come on! It makes you change all your project because of one asyncio usage. Tell me this is not true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Come on! It makes you change all your project because of one asyncio
>   usage. Tell me this is not true.

It's true

Whole idea of using `await` keyword is to execute concurrent jobs in one event loop from different places of the code (which you can't do with regular function code).

`asyncio` - is not some utility, but whole style of writing asynchronous programs.

---

On the other hand Python is very flexible, so you can still try to hide using of asyncio. If you really want to get sync result of 3 Fetcher instances, you can for example do something like this:

```
import asyncio


def sync_exec(coro):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)


class Fetcher:
    async def async_get_result(self):
        # async interface:
        async def async_job():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            return id(self)
        return (await async_job())

    def get_result(self):
        # sync interface:
        return sync_exec(self.async_get_result())

    @classmethod
    def get_results(cls, *fetchers):
        # sync interface multiple:
        return sync_exec(
            asyncio.gather(*[fetcher.async_get_result() for fetcher in fetchers])
        )        



# single sync get_result:
f1 = Fetcher()
print('Result: ', f1.get_result())


# multiple sync get_result:
f2 = Fetcher()
f3 = Fetcher()
print('Results: ', Fetcher.get_results(f1, f2, f3))
```

Output:

```
Result:  2504097887120
Results:  [2504097887120, 2504104854416, 2504104854136]
```

But, again, you'll really regret someday if you continue to write code this way, believe me. If you want to get full advantage of asynchronous programming - use `coroutines` and `await` explicitly.

Comment: These two separate worlds, sync and async, make transition to asyncio unacceptably complicated :( Maybe I'll change my mind after creating fully async tool. Anyway thank you for the answer.

Comment: That's a great approach for a library shared between both new asyncio-based and synchronous legacy code.

Comment: but you can only use run_until_complete() once as asyncio doesn't support nested async calls...if there are more than one async functions, the above way won't work.

Comment: Only one event loop is a deal-breaker for my use case. Interested if there is another solution.