# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'function' was never awaited

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have a class `PersonalMessage` with a function `sendPersonalMessage` that sends a message to a user in telegram.

```
class PersonalMessage:
def __init__(self):
    self.api_id = api_id,
    self.api_hash = api_hash,
    self.token = token,
    self.user_id_1 = user_id_1,
    self.phone = phone

async def sendPersonalMessage(self, message, user_id):
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    try:
        receiver = InputPeerUser(user_id, 0)
        await client.send_message(receiver, message, parse_mode='html')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    client.disconnect()
```

when I try to call the function in the main .py file like this:

```
elif there_exists(['send', 'send']):
    speak("What should I send?")
    response = takeCommand()
    PersonalMessage().sendPersonalMessage(response, user_id_1)
```

it gives me this error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'PersonalMessage().sendPersonalMessage(response, user_id_1)' was never awaited`

Comment: Well, the error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: `sendPersonalMessage` is a coroutine (it is declared with `await def`) but you did not await it.  So it never runs.  You need an `await` in front of the method call.

Comment: Yes, but where do I add the async, the if statements are wrapped in a while loop

Comment: The function that contains the await must be declared `async def`.

Comment: In the sendPersonalMessage() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do `await PersonalMessage().sendPersonalMessage(response, user_id_1)` instead of using `asyncio.run` to execute this individual coroutine, unless you want to lose the benefits of using asyncio (ability to run other coroutines concurrently).

`asyncio.run` should be the entry point of your whole program, and all your functions dealing with I/O should be declared as `async def`. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33357233/1113207) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45213133/1113207) elaborate a bit further.

Answer (score 1):

I got it I just had to import `asyncio` and wrap the function like this:

```
elif there_exists(['send', 'send']):
    speak("What should I send?")
    response = takeCommand()
    asyncio.run(PersonalMessage().sendPersonalMessage(response, user_id_1))
    speak("Message sent successfully")
```

Comment: No, you should probably do `await PersonalMessage().sendPersonalMessage(response, user_id_1)` instead, unless you want to lose the benefits of using asyncio (ability to run other coroutines concurrently). `asyncio.run` should be the entry point of your whole program and all your functions dealing with I/O should be declared as `async def`. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33357233/1113207) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45213133/1113207) elaborate a bit further.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer?