# Is there an alternative process to threading for async process in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, python-multithreading

Please tell me if there is a better way to do this in python.

I have an endpoint in the flask app that takes in the request, validate, and starts a thread and returns a response saying request if valid and a process is started.
At the end of the thread, I will send a request to the call back URL saying the threading process has completed.

1. is there a way to do this without threading?
2. what are the other options to do an asynchronous endpoint call in python where the client doesn't till the process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using features from Python 3.4+'s [asyncio](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/). This will change the working of the program to cooperative multitasking, so need to be a bit careful. Some answers on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841985/make-a-python-asyncio-call-from-a-flask-route).
2. Maybe websockets would work for you. The [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/) framework is async-first and has inbuilt websocket support.